# C: validity of pointers

Tags: c

I've written this code to read values from a file, and if a read value is a ";" is, all values that occurred up to now and were written in a string should be written into a field of a pointer array

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <windows.h>
    #define SIZE_STRINGS 100
    #define SIZE_ZS 15

    int index_drei;
    char *laenge_drei[SIZE_STRINGS];

    char* string_to_pointer(char []);
    void laengen_block_nach_siegen_ordnen();

    void spielweg_nach_laenge_des_spieweges_ordnen(bool spieler)
    {
        int i,
            laenge,
            index_zs;
        char buchstabe,
             zs[SIZE_ZS],
             zs2[SIZE_ZS],
             *zs_p;
        bool akt_laenge_auslesen;
        FILE * fp;

        if(spieler)
            fp = fopen("Anlagen\\spielweg_spieler.txt", "r"); //Datei öffnen
        else
            fp = fopen("Anlagen\\spielweg_ai.txt", "r"); //Datei öffnen

        akt_laenge_auslesen = true;
        index_drei = 0;

        laenge = 0;
        index_zs = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < SIZE_ZS; i++)
        {
            zs[i] = 0;
        }

        if(fp == NULL)
        {
        }else
        {
            while((buchstabe = fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
            {
                zs[index_zs] = buchstabe;
                index_zs++;
                if(akt_laenge_auslesen == true && buchstabe == '-')
                    akt_laenge_auslesen = false;
                else if(akt_laenge_auslesen)
                    laenge = buchstabe - '0';
                else if(buchstabe == ';')
                {
                    if(laenge == 3)
                    {
                        laenge_drei[index_drei] = string_to_pointer(zs);
                        /*Firts value*/
                        strcpy(zs2, laenge_drei[0]);
                        printf("%s", zs2);Sleep(1000);
                        index_drei++;
                    }
                    akt_laenge_auslesen = true;
                    laenge = 0;
                    index_zs = 0;
                    for(i = 0; i < SIZE_ZS; i++)
                    {
                        zs[i] = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
            /*Second value*/
            strcpy(zs2, laenge_drei[0]);
            printf("%s", zs2);Sleep(1000);
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

    char* string_to_pointer(char string[])
    {
        return string;
    }
```

If I write the value from "length_drei [0]" with strcpy in string "zs2", I get:

- / * First value * / the right value
- / * Second value * / the wrong value (one space)

Comment: I'm pretty tired, so it could be me, but I never see you allocate memory for the individual strings that you are copying.  You are just assigning the memory reference to `zs` over and over again.

Comment: laenge_drei[index_drei] = string_to_pointer(zs);

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  `EOF` doesn't fit into a `char`.

Comment: Yes, but it will then be spun directly from the Ascii code to a char and it will exit the loop when you reach EOF.

Comment: @MaxJanorschke make it int. There is a reason why all char functions take and return `int`s - not chars. Trust us

Comment: `laenge_drei[index_drei] = string_to_pointer(zs);`  the entries in your pointer array will all point into the same`zs`, which is a local variable. (and the  `string_to_opointer()` function does nothing. Maybe you want `strdup()`?)

Comment: @MaxJanorschke I saw that line, but that does not allocate a string.  It sets element `index_drei` in an array of char pointers to point at the location of `zs`

Answer (score 2):

You aren't allocating any memory for the string segments you're trying to save in `laenge_drei`.  At the end of the loop, each index of `laenge_drei` contains a reference to `zs` and therefore the last string processed.

```c
if(laenge == 3)
{
    laenge_drei[index_drei] = strdup(zs);
    printf("%s", laenge_drei[index_drei]);
    sleep(1000);
    index_drei++;
}
```

Change `strcpy(zs2, laenge_drei[0])` to `strcpy(zs2, laenge_drei[index_drei])` if you're trying to print out each segment or you'll just keep printing the first one over and over again.

When you exit the loop & try to print `laenge_drei[0]` again, it will still have the first value.  Don't forget to free your memory.

Comment: make that `1+strlen(zs)`, or: use `strdup()`

Comment: I get no output

Comment: @MaxJanorschke - have you tried to debug it?  I simplified the code a bit per wildplasser's suggestion.  You shouldn't need to copy anything to `zs2` if you're just printing the values of the indices of `laenge_drei`